# Java: for loop, incompatible types

Tags: java, loops, boolean, int, for-loop

I'm trying to run this for loop;

```
        for (int col= 0; grid[0].length; col++)
```

However every time I try to compile I get an error stating 'incompatible types - found int but expected boolean'

I can't work out what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: for (int col= 0; col<grid[0].length; col++) {} // you should consider reading a java text book

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the second statement: grid[0].length is an integer.  The second statement in a for loop is a condition statement and needs to be a boolean.

If you're trying to loop while col is less than the length of grid[0], then you need this as your second statement:

col < grid[0].length;

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int col= 0; col < grid[0].length; col++)   // See the typo
```

Answer (score 2):

`grid[0].length` is the integer that the message refered to. A boolean value was expected there:

```
col < grid[0].length
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code to something like:
`for (int col= 0; col<grid[0].length; col++)`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in where this is specified: Check out [docs.oracle.com](https://docs.oracle.com) for the Java Language Specification.  Chapter 14 §14.1 states the rules for a basic for loop:

```
BasicForStatement:
  for ( [ForInit] ; [Expression] ; [ForUpdate] ) Statement
```

with the addendum that:

> **The type of the *Expression* must be boolean or Boolean, or a compile-time error occurs.**

This particular citation was taken from the Java SE 17 specification. Since this post was 11+ years ago, (almost twelve at the time of this response) the question likely refers to Java SE 7, which has the same rule and almost the same verbiage verbatim.