# Java Switch Incompatible Error w/ Switchs

Tags: java, jgrasp

We're supposed to make a program in computer science that figures out what day of the week you were born on. We were given these instructions. 
1)  Start with the last two digits of the year in which you were born.
2)  Divide the above number by 4, dropping the remainder if there is one.
3)  Find the number associated with the month in which you were born in the Table of Months.
4)  On which day of the month is your birthday?
5)  Find the sum of the four numbers obtained in steps 1 through 4.
6)  Divide the sum by the number 7.  The day that corresponds to the remainder in the Table of Days is the day of the week you were born on.

Table of Months                                    Table of Days
January 1 (0 in leap year)                         Sunday   1
February 4 (3 in leap year)                        Monday   2
March   4                                          Tuesday  3
April   0                                         Wednesday 4
May 2                                              Thursday 5
June    5                                          Friday   6
July    0                                          Saturday 0
August  3
September 6
October 1
November 4
December 6

I've been having trouble with is incomparable types: int and boolean, i don't know what the problem is, ive tried changing variables to boolean, but it doesn't solve anything.

```
package LeapYear;
import java.util.*;
public class Birthday
{
   static Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main (String []args)
    {  

      int year=getYear();
      int month=getMonth(year);
      int day=getDay();
      int total=computeDay(day, month, year);
      int dayofbirth=dayOfWeek(day,month,year);

}//end main
        public static int getYear()
        {   

            System.out.println("Please enter the last two digits of the year you were born:");
            int y=in.nextInt();
            return y;
        }
        public static int getMonth(int year)
        {
            int m;
            System.out.println("Please select the month in which you were born:"+
                        "1.)Januaryn\n"+
                        "2.)February\n"+
                        "3.)March\n"+
                        "4.)April\n"+
                        "5.)May\n"+
                        "6.)June\n"+
                        "7.)July\n"+
                        "8.)August\n"+
                        "9.)September\n"+
                        "10.)October\n"+
                        "11.)November\n"+
                        "12.)December\n");
            m=in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("You entered " + m);
                        switch(m)
                        {
                            case 1: if(year ==true)
                        return 0;
                    else
                            return 1 ;
                            break;
                            case 2:if(year == true)
                            return 3;
                    else
                            return 4;
                            break;
                            case 3:return 4;
                            break;
                            case 4:return 0;
                            break;
                            case 5:return 2;
                    break;
                            case 6:return 5;
                            break;
                            case 7:return 0;
                            break;
                            case 8:return 3;
                            break;
                            case 9:return 6;
                            break;
                            case 10:return 1;
                            break;
                            case 11:return 4;
                            break;
                            case 12:return 6;
                            break;      

                        }//end case

        }//end getMonth
        public static int getDay()
        {
            int d;
            System.out.println("Please enter the day on which you were born");
            d=in.nextInt();
            return d;

        }//end getDay
        public static int computeDay(int day, int month, int year)
        {
            int weekday;
            int y2=year/4;
        int m2= month + y2 + day;
        int total=m2/7;
        return total;

        }//end computeDay
     public static int dayOfWeek(int day, int month, int year, int total)
     {
        int dob;
           switch(dob)
           {
           case 1:if (total=1)
           System.out.println("You were born on a Sunday");
           break;
           case 2:if (total=2)
           System.out.println("You were born on a Monday");
           break;
           case 3: if (total=3)
           System.out.println("You were born on a Tuesday");
           break;
           case 4: if(total=4)
           System.out.println("You were born on a Wednesday");
           break;
           case 5: if(total=5);
           System.out.println("You were born on a Thursday");
           break;
           case 6: if (total=6);
           System.out.println("You were born on a Friday");
           break;
           case 7: if (total=7);
           System.out.println("You were born on a Saturday");
           break;
           }


     }//end dayOfWeek




}//end class
```

Comment: `total=1` should be `total==1`. Same applies to your other `if` conditions.

Comment: How can a number be true?

Comment: Seems like every question that mentions assignment or homework gets downvoted. Does it really matter if people ask for help on their homework? How else can one learn? Upvoted in retaliation.

Comment: @localhost The post was most likely downvoted because the error itself is pretty self explanatory, and since it is such a common one there are many questions already addressing this problem on this site. For example look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378052/java-for-loop-incompatible-types). Simply type "incompatible types" into the search bar on the top right of this page and you will see there are currently 10,817 questions that address this issue.

Comment: @Takendarkk Point taken.

Answer (score 1):

`if(year == true)` cannot compile because an integer cannot be true. Do something useful with that statement like:

```
if(year < 50)
{
    System.out.println("Wow, you're old!");
    return 0;
}
```

Because you are only getting the last two digits of their year of birth, you will have trouble deciding if the user was born in the year 1905 or 2005. This is an unlikely case, but you would not be able to decipher whether the user was born this century or the last. If it is acceptable not to know, don't change it. If not, you will need to get more information from the user.